# Why are so many packages being installed under node_modules?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, asp.net-core

I'm trying to understand how NPM works with VS 2015 and .Net Core. I am following this tutorial: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/283/asp-net-5-managing-client-side-dependencies-with-npm-bower-and-gulp

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8"
  }
}
```

I was expecting to have Gulp, Gulp-Contact, Gulp-Cssmin, Gulp-Uglify, and Rimraf under src/node_modules. Instead I am seeing more than 200 packages and of the packages listed in my package.json, only Gulp appears to be installed.

How can I remove the pacakges I don't want and how can I ensure the packages I need are installed?

**EDIT:** Digging further into this, I tried running `npm cache clear` from Powershell in my project directory with admin privileges and I got this error:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache'`

This was surprising to me because I was expecting the cache to clear src/node_modules. Does anyone know which version of Node that Visual Studio uses? And / or where the node.exe that VS uses is normally located *(using Win 10)*.

Running `npm cache clear` from Visual Studio Package Manager Console (running VS as admin) cleared everything up. I'm still not sure why that worked.

Comment: npm flattens dependancies.

Comment: Okay, so all those packages are all dependencies of the packages in my package.json?

Comment: @smulholland2: The reason why they are flattened is to reduce hdd storage and bandwidth. If Package A and B has a dependency on same version of package C, then C would be downloaded twice before. Once in A's node_module and once in B's node_module folder. The other one: Avoid issues with windows max path length. When you have to many nested folders they may be issues on Windows

Answer (score 0):

If your packages get out of sync, like mine were, follow these steps to eliminate unwanted packages and ensure you have the ones listed in your package.json.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete bower_components and node_modules directories in src.
3. Reopen VS with admin privieges but do not reopen the project.
4. Run `npm cache clear` from Package Manager console.

**Note:** `npm` must be an environment variable do you will have to either install Node.js or set Visual Studios Node.js to PATH.

This is a good post on how to use a new version of `npm` than what comes installed with VS2015. http://jameschambers.com/2015/09/upgrading-npm-in-visual-studio-2015/